# Modifying Multiple XML Documents Using Foreach using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I created a script to loop through our user directories and modify and XML document to change a setting in an application. Normally when I use a `foreach` it would make my variable = one item from collection. Instead this script is putting everything from `$XMLPaths` into my `$Path` variable.

```bsh
$XMLPaths = Get-ChildItem \\DFSRoot\DFSShare\view\Profiles\*\AppData\Roaming\Trillian\ -Recurse -Force |
            Where-Object {$_.Name -contains 'Events.xml'} |
            Select FullName |
            FT -HideTableHeaders |
            Out-String

foreach ($Path in $XMLPaths) {
  $xml = [xml](Get-Content $Path)
  $node = $xml.events.prefs.setting | Where {$_.Name -eq 'Sounds'}
  $node.value = '1'
  $XML.Save($Path)
  $Path
  $node
}
```

Here is the XML document I am using.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE events
        PUBLIC "--//IETF//DTD RFCxxxx XEVENTS 1.0//EN" "xevents.dtd">

<!-- WARNING: This is a generated file by Trillian.  Do not update while -->
<!--          Trillian is running otherwise updates will be erased       -->

    <events>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <Prefs>
            <setting name="idle" value="1"/>
            <setting name="sounds" value="1"/>
            <setting name="sounds_away" value="1"/>
            <setting name="sounds_suppress" value="1"/>
            <setting name="automatic_outbound" value="1"/>
            <setting name="hide_disabled" value="1"/>
            <setting name="video_capture" value="1"/>
            <setting name="buzz_sound" value="1"/>
            <setting name="game_status" value="0"/>
            <setting name="awaymessage_song" value="0"/>
            <setting name="awaymessage_autosave" value="1"/>
            <setting name="awaymessage_update2" value="1"/>
            <setting name="away_autoresponse" value="0"/>
        </Prefs>
        <AwayList>
            <AwayGroup name="Root">
                <AwayMessage label="Set%20all%20Do%20Not%20Disturb" text="" awayState="1" awayMenu="1" autoRespond="0" system="1">
                    <Status medium="ASTRA" type="Do%20Not%20Disturb"/>
                </AwayMessage>
                <AwayMessage label="Set%20all%20Offline" text="" awayState="1" awayMenu="0" autoRespond="1" system="1">
                    <Status medium="ASTRA" type="Offline"/>
                </AwayMessage>
                <AwayMessage label="Set%20all%20Away" text="Away%20since%20%25time%25%20%28%25timeZoneOffset%25%29" awayState="1" awayMenu="1" autoRespond="1" system="1">
                    <Status medium="ASTRA" type="Away"/>
                </AwayMessage>
                <AwayMessage label="Set%20all%20Invisible" text="" awayState="1" awayMenu="1" autoRespond="0" system="1">
                    <Status medium="ASTRA" type="Invisible"/>
                </AwayMessage>
                <AwayMessage label="Set%20all%20Back" text="" awayState="0" awayMenu="1" autoRespond="0" system="1">
                    <Status medium="ASTRA" type="Online"/>
                </AwayMessage>
                <AwayMessage label="Set%20all%20Idle" text="Idle%20since%20%25time%25%20%28%25timeZoneOffset%25%29" awayState="1" awayMenu="0" autoRespond="1" system="1">
                    <Status medium="ASTRA" type="Away"/>
                </AwayMessage>
            </AwayGroup>
        </AwayList>
    </events>
```

The variable `$Path` which should only have one directory in it at a time instead has this in it.

```
\\DFSROOT\DFSSHare\view\Profiles\User1\AppData\Roaming\Trillian\users\User1\Events.xml
\\DFSROOT\DFSSHare\view\Profiles\User2\AppData\Roaming\Trillian\users\User2\Events.xml
\\DFSROOT\DFSSHare\view\Profiles\User3\AppData\Roaming\Trillian\users\User3\Events.xml
\\DFSROOT\DFSSHare\view\Profiles\User4\AppData\Roaming\Trillian\users\User4\Events.xml
\\DFSROOT\DFSSHare\view\Profiles\User5\AppData\Roaming\Trillian\users\User5\Events.xml
```

Comment: Do not use `Format-Table` as intermediate step in pipeline.

Comment: Also don't use `Out-String` unless you actually intend the result to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in that your resulting `$XMLPaths` variable is a **string** and not an **array**. Thus, your ForEach expression interprets the variable `$XMLPaths` as an array of one element, with the one element being a string containing all of the paths concatenated together.

You can always check the type of a variable `$Variable` by typing `$Variable.GetType()`. For example, when I ran your first line of code this is what I saw:

```
PS > $XMLPaths.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name    BaseType
-------- -------- ----    --------
True     True     String  System.Object
```

Try replacing the first line with this:

```
#Remote Computers
$XMLPaths = (Get-ChildItem \\DFSRoot\DFS Share\view\Profiles\*\AppData\Roaming\Trillian\ -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.Name -contains 'Events.xml'} | Select FullName).FullName
```

After the `Select FullName` clause, an array of objects that contain the property `FullName` is returned. So by calling `.FullName` on that, it returns an array of the file names.

You should be able to check that `$XMLPaths` is of type array:

```
PS > $XMLPaths.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name      BaseType
-------- -------- ----      --------
True     True     Object[]  System.Array
```

Answer (score 0):

`$XMLPaths.GetType().Name` returns `String`. Use

```
$auxiliaryPath = "\\DFSRoot\DFS Share\view\Profiles\*\AppData\Roaming\Trillian"
$XMLPaths = (Get-ChildItem "$auxiliaryPath\Events.xml" -Recurse -Force).FullName
```